# Can I access controller action from the header.php view in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, methods, header, helper

I just want to access a specific method of a class from my header.php file in CodeIgniter. I tried with creating a helper. But it just ruins all of my page content from loading. 
It says I can't use `$this` inside header.php.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include your code for reference sake =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `$this` you can do:

```
$ci = &get_instance();
```

and use `$ci` just like `$this`
for example `$ci->model->function();`